# Compiling code is taking too much time in sharelatex

Tags: compiling

What's wrong with my code? it's not compiling through Sharelatex(It will take a long time and then it will produce timed out error)

```
\documentclass{article}[15pt]
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]
\draw [->, ultra thick, red](0,6)--(0,-6) node[right]{$x$};
\draw [->,ultra thick, red](6,0)--(-6,0) node[above]{$y$};
\draw (6,-2)--(-6,6);
\draw (6,6)--(-6,-2);
\draw[very thick,red]
--(3,1) node {$\tan\theta_2$};
\fill[green!20!white] (3,0)-- ++(4mm,0mm)
arc[start angle=0, end angle=143.130102, radius=4mm]--cycle
\fill[green!20!white] (-3,0)-- ++(3mm,0mm)
arc[start angle=0, end angle=56.3099, radius=4mm]--cycle
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You forgot to finish the `\fill` commands with `;` (Just after every cycle)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because Ti*k*Z got stuck reading the last two `\fill`s because you are missing the semicolon at the end:

```
\documentclass{article}[15pt]
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]
\draw [->, ultra thick, red](0,6)--(0,-6) node[right]{$x$};
\draw [->,ultra thick, red](6,0)--(-6,0) node[above]{$y$};
\draw (6,-2)--(-6,6);
\draw (6,6)--(-6,-2);
\draw[very thick,red]
--(3,1) node {$\tan\theta_2$};
\fill[green!20!white] (3,0)-- ++(4mm,0mm)
arc[start angle=0, end angle=143.130102, radius=4mm]--cycle;% <- HERE
\fill[green!20!white] (-3,0)-- ++(3mm,0mm)
arc[start angle=0, end angle=56.3099, radius=4mm]--cycle;% <- AND HERE
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you;I didn't noticed that

Comment: It's quite common thing to happen (I say by experience :P). The problem is that ShareLatex doesn't show the log files (as far as I know), so it's hard to tell the problem. When using the command line the error appears instantly: `! Package tikz Error: Giving up on this path. Did you forget a semicolon?.`